# javascript: window-object is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

I´m trying to attach the resize-event of the window within an self-developed-jquery-extension. It looks like this:

```
$(window).resize(function ()
{
    this.trigger();
}.bind(this));
```

I wondered that this event is never triggered and recognized that the window-object is undefined. But I cannot find any reason why. The extension is in a script-tag of a html-snippet which is loaded via ajax and inserted into the DOM. This extension should be triggered after the document has been completed.

```
<script>
    jQuery(function()
    {
        jQuery('#myId').myExtension();
    });
</script>
```

I found out at the MDN that the window-object is referenced in the document:

```
window.defaultView
```

So I tried the following:

```
document.defaultView.addEventListener('onresize', function ()
{ 
    //...
});
```

Indeed defaultView has an object but this alternative has also no result!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I made a mistake: I declared a variable with the name "window" in a if-block some lines before... I didn´t see that.

Comment: you helped me @xforfun.  I did the same idiotic thing!